# Completing a Microbiology PhD in a hospital research institute rather than university

Tags: phd, biology, medicine

I'm considering doing my PhD work in a research institute of a hospital which is associated with my university (joint appointments). What are some advantages and disadvantages to this? Is it wise to just join a lab on campus?

Comment: Can you make your particular concerns more explicit?

Comment: Doesn't it depend strongly on the type of research that will happen in each place?